# How to recognize CPU architecture in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a direct download link which i want to detect the mobile CPU architecture but the download link is on Web, and NOT on Android.
Cause I'm working with React.js
I wrote 5 different APKs for 5 different CPUs and want to handle it on web so if you click on the button React.js handle the CPU recognition, cause most users don't know their own CPU architecture.
I hope I made my point here.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't quite understand, is this running in a browser or in something like React Native?  The browser explicitly and consciously hides information like this.  Best you can do is user agent sniffing which is trivially spoofed.

Comment: In a browser in a mobile or PWA.

Comment: check `window.navigator.userAgent`